# C++ OpenCV 3.4 Can't find an image

Tags: c++, opencv

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
     Mat image;

     image = imread("Test.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
     if(image.empty())
     {
         std::cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
         return -1;
     }

     namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

     imshow("Display window", image);

     waitKey(0);

}
```

I wrote this bit of code, but somehow it can't find the image.If I create a new image inside the "Resource Files" folder it works perfectly fine. Both images are inside the folder.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Because you gave a relative path as filename argument. Your code will either work or not, depending on the environment where it is executed.

Comment: Even if the image is in the Resource Files folder of this certain project?

Comment: Even if, because you can move your executable and run it outside VS environment.

Comment: Ty but it doesn't even work inside inside the VS environment. So how can I make it work at all?

Comment: have a look at the "working directory" setting in you VS project settings. By default it's not the folder where the executable is placed, afair.

Comment: Thank you Micka. It works now.